# Serving in house ad inventory with iAd

Tags: ios, iad

Is it possible to use the iAd SDK and iAd Workbench to serve in house ad inventory in an application?

If not, what are some of the best SDK's to serve your own inventory of in house ads in an iOS application? DFP/Admob SDK's aren't that customizable for native ads.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to use the iAd SDK and iAD workbench to serve house
>   inventory in app?

No, it is not possible to serve in house ads using iAd.

> If not, what are some of the best SDKs to serve your own inventory in
>   an iOS app?

I have custom implementations in a few applications but I mostly use AdMob.